Twelve Rolling Month calculation by grouping existing and past three quarters
I have following test dataset: https://dbfiddle.uk/A5QVnwXe
I want to calculate sum for current and past three quarter prices rows on a rolling basis.
The code that I tried in power bi with the result I got:
Test_12RM = 
var _selecteddate = MAXX(ALLSELECTED(TestTable), [ClosingDate]) 

return if( ISFILTERED(TestTable[ClosingDate].[QuarterNo]), 
CALCULATE( sum(TestTable[Price]), DATESINPERIOD(TestTable[ClosingDate],
_selecteddate,-4, QUARTER)), 
SUMX(ALLSELECTED(TestTable), [Price]) )


This just shows result for the last quarter grouping, while I want results for last quarter group, the quarter before last quarter group until the top 3 quarters are left when group of 4 is not possible. Ideally in this form of table in power bi

raw data:

excel calculation:


what the code for every quarter is the same? Is last table the expected output?

yes the code for calculation should be same, just that it should be a loop that stops when group of 4 quarters is not possible. It is the design I want the expected output to be, sum_price values are not accurate.

you can create a calendar table and create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _start =
    EDATE ( MAX ( 'date'[Date] ), -12 ) + 1
VAR _min =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'date'[Date] ), ALL ( 'date' ) )
RETURN
    IF (
        _start < _min,
        BLANK (),
        SUMX (
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Table' ),
                'Table'[Closing Date] >= _start
                    && 'Table'[Closing Date] <= MAX ( 'date'[Date] )
            ),
            'Table'[Price]
        )
    )



pls try this
Measure =
IF (
    EDATE (
        DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), ROUNDUP ( MONTH ( TODAY () ) / 3, 0 ) * 3, 31 ),
        -1
    )
        >= MAX ( 'date'[Date] ),
    9999
)


and replace 9999 with your current measure.
below is the raw data you provided.

this is the expected output

could you pls clarify how to get the output from the sample data?

I tried the code above and got the following result. I have attached the expected results below too.
[![result_obtained]
: https://i.sstatic.net/Tr9QOGJj.png
[![expected result]
: https://i.sstatic.net/Fgkm4gVo.png

could you pls provide some sample data not the screenshot of table visual.

This is the dataset I applied the code you gave on to get result_obtained: https://dbfiddle.uk/A5QVnwXe

Expected result row 1(qtr 4 2023) is sum of price of all 2023 rows in dataset since I'm looking to sum on group of current(qtr 4 2023) and past three quarters(qtr 3,2,1 2023)

update my comments in the answer since we can't paste pics here. pls clarify the calculation logic

not sure if comment got updated without approval but added all screenshots in the original question. Apologies for mistake in the calculation before, I added calculation formula in excel screenshot.
